# How to properly return an object that is equal to null? (simplified bst)

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I've tried to implement a binary-search-tree(BST) insert using the following method but i really don't get why i get the value instead of the actual "reference" to the node.

I've done other implementations that worked fine but I really want to understand why instead of getting the pointer to let's say `node.m_left` I get just it's value (`null`).

How can I get that without resorting to unsafe code ?
The reason i'm choosing this way is because searching and inserting are closely related and i don't want to implement the same thing twice.

```
public void Add(int value)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = new Node(value);
        return;
    }
    Node parent = null , 
         res;
    //finding the correct place
    res = Find(value, root, ref parent);

    if (res == null) //probably redunant
    {
        //once found create a node and asign it's parent
        res = new Node(value);
        res.m_parent = parent;
    }
    //EvaluateAVT(res);


}

private Node Find(int value, Node node, ref Node parent,bool justfind = false)
{

    if (node.Data == value && justfind)
    {
        return node;
    }
    if (node.Data >= value)
    {
        if (node.m_left == null)
        {
           parent = node;
           return node.m_left;
        }
        return Find(value,node.m_left,ref parent ,justfind);
    }
    else
    {
        if (node.m_right == null)
        {
            parent = node;
            return node.m_right;
        }
        return Find(value, node.m_right, ref parent, justfind);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't currently return a reference to something. It is slated for inclusion in C# 7 but not as of yet. Right now you can only return the *value* of the variable. Or you can resort to unsafe code and pointers but this is not recommended.

Comment: I don't think this will compile: `Node parent = null , 
                 res;`

Comment: @rory.ap That will compile just fine and declares a variable `parent` with an initial value of `null` as well as a variable named `res` that doesn't have an initial value.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen -- ahh, thanks.  I've never seen that before.

Comment: That should take the pressure out of the rest of your day then :) Everybody should strive to learn something new each day and you just did, now you're free to tinker without having to worry about learning anything until tomorrow :)

Comment: As a tip for the question, you would either have to return a reference to the parent node, and let the caller also decide wether to store something in the left or the right branch, or you have to return something that encapsulates the parent node, the direction, and a way to set the branch value. This could be a separate type. In other words, you would return something that encapsulates *how* to place a new node and *where* to place it.

Comment: won't setting `parent.m_left = res` (or `m_right`) below `res.m_parent = parent` do what you need?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , i want to avoid that, as i said i've wrote code that works (one of the ideas was the one u've suggested(having a boolean) ) it feels really "unclean" to me for some reason or even allocating it feels like repeating code which is not elegant thing

Comment: Yes, but as I stated, you can't really return a "reference to the left child of a parent node so that it can be both read and written to" without encapsulating it in the current version of the language.

Comment: You can read more about this proposed feature here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/118

Comment: @slawekwin it will but it will require me to get additional information (a right/left boolean or some sort) which i'm not interested in, what i really would like is a reference to that Node(the node itself not it's value) but lasse v. karlsen said i can't :/ so i'll resort to that kind of solution again

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ty mate! i've actually tried to write the prototype as private ref Node Find(int value, Node node, ref Node parent,bool justfind = false) , hehe i wish they'd implement it :)

Comment: I see it's simple `node.Data >= value` evaluation, but in case it was just a simplified version, you could write a delegate argument not to implement it twice (`Func<bool, Node, int> lrPredicate = (node, value) => node.Data >= value`

Comment: What you really want is to return a *variable*, not a *value*. You want to return something that you can assign to, and this assignment will then be done to the relevant child reference inside the tree. The underlying IL supports this in fact but C# does not (currently) have a way to exploit this support. This is what is proposed to be added in C# 7.